# memory limit destroying session

Tags: php, session, memory-size

The question is simple.

If during the running of script is encoutred exhausted memory size, is then SESSION unset?

Scenario:

On my dev server, i have big memory limit, when i upload a lot of images, everything is OK.

On my production server, when i upload 5+ images of 1MB, my script stop with fatal error with memory size exhausted. That's OK, i can handle upload differently, but what's not OK is that if user isn't using login cookies which rebuild session, user is logouted...

So the question is. If script reach memory size limit, is SESSION removed?

Comment: how does subsequent requests identify the session without cookies?

Comment: What server are you using (apache, IIS, ngenx)?

Comment: @drew_w Linux apache24-php55-3 3.14.4-031404-generic

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 user login is stored in session, if he is inactive for 30minutes, session is invalided...if user try to log again, script check cookies, if cookies are found and are OK, user is logged, but with fewer rights(login withou pass) and his user info is stored in session

Comment: there is something being lost in translation here. I literally can't make sense of what your saying... the session requires a cookie with an ID to be set in-order for the next request to identify what session to use.. "user isn't using login cookies which rebuild session" ... how does the session work without this??

Comment: Set your post limit so you don't get out of memory errors. And the session isn't unset, the cookie will still be on their machine, the file will still exist, it's only changes that will be lost, since the session is only written on calling `session_write_close` or when it reaches a normal end of execution.

Comment: when user is logging, there's created session id cookie and in session his user info, but if he check remember me, there are stored in cookie two more hashes...when files are uploaded, if he isn't using remember me, after memory exhausted, his session is destroyed/removed and is logouted...if he is using remember me, he is autentificated with those cookie hashes and marked as logged with cookies, which recreate his user session...

Comment: @scragar I'm trying just to read session, not set or update it...but it's not there

Comment: If you record the session ID from when it is working and try to retrieve the session with that ID using something like `<pre><?php if(isset($_GET['s'])){session_id($_GET['s']); session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); } else {session_start(); echo '<a href="?s=' . session_id().'">Click</a>';}`